# Why does connecting PC to the router automatically solve DNS related issues?

Tags: networking, router, dns

I'm trying to diagnose a really peculiar network issue.

**tl;dr:** The browser can't resolve DNS most of the time when the PC is connected directly to the wall. The problem goes away if the router is plugged to the wall and the PC is plugged to the PC.

Here's the problem: when the PC is connected directly to the wall (Ethernet socket, University network), web browsing would present many challenges because the browser runs into issues resolving the DNS (on chrome, it would often comeback with an error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET). Usually, I'd have to refresh the page 2-3 times for it to finally load the page. Sometimes, I get lucky and it only takes one try, sometimes I have to refresh the page around 5 or more times. I'm faced with the same issue with other browsers as well, such as IE or Firefox.

For any other connections that doesn't involve DNS, such as gaming over UDP or direct IP connection to another machine, the connection works perfectly.

Here's relevant specs of PC:

```
OS: Windows 10
Motherboard: MSI z97 Gaming 5
On-Board Ethernet: Killer e2200 gigabit Ethernet
```

Here's couple of things I've tried:

```
1) Reinstall network driver. Both using the standard suite (200MB) and just the inf files (440kb)

2) Set DNS to google's public dns (8.8.8.8)

3) ipconfig /flushdns, ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew, netsh winsock reset

4) Try browsing on internet from virtual machine (VMWare Windows XP)

5) Boot from Ubuntu Live CD
```

In all 5 cases, I'd get a similar issue.

Naturally, I thought it's either my ISP or my onboard network card at fault. But here's the really weird part: As soon as I try to connect my Belkin Router to the wall, then my PC to the router, the problem completely disappears! To confirm I'm not just seeing things, I've tried to connect the PC straight back to wall again, and the problem came back. So clearly, connecting the router somehow resolves the issue.

I've never come across an issue like this. Why does connecting a router automatically fix DNS related issues? What are some good techniques of determining what voodoo magic my router is doing to the DNS? If possible, I'd like to understand the exact problem here so I can troubleshoot issues like this in the future.

Comment: Do you have a switch inbetween? edit: ow wait directly connected to the wall. Maybe its keeping some form of cookie's in cache did you try clearing it?

Comment: @DylanRz Yes, I've tried clearing all caches as well.

Comment: @Xiague Did you try switching ethernet cables?

Comment: @DylanRz Yes that has been tried

Comment: I believe have been facing similar situation (with 1 pc running multiple OS) and would like to add one observation I made : while my computer was totaly unable to make dns requests, if a working computer on the same network made a dns request for the same website I was trying to reach then my non working compture would be able to access said website as if it had eavesdropped on the dns resolution of the working one. Do you observe similar behaviour ?

Comment: @Xiagua Can you provide the output of `ipconfig /all` from both locations?

Answer (score 0):

Some countries would pollute the public DNS like Google (8.8.8.8) in order to prevent citizens accessing unwanted websites. This may create the illusion you mentioned in the OP (have to refresh 0-5 times to get the page). I suggest you do the following:

1. Search for the local DNS provider and use them on your PC
2. Setup an automatic fetch DNS provider on your router and let your PC lookup the DNS from the router

I don't believe there's any difference between your PC being directly connected to the router and connected to the wall. this should only matter if the cable in the wall is damaged, or it has another router before the link goes to your PC.

Please check the IP address and do some pings to eliminate those possibilities.

Comment: I'm connecting from US, so the idea of polluting public DNS (especially if it's google) sounds very strange. Aside from the automatic fetching of DNS (Defaults to my local DNS provider), I've tried two other DNS. Same issue. What do you mean by check IP address though?

Comment: I mean I don't know if you have connected to another router throuth the wall, because it can't be seen. By checking the IP address on you PC, and compare it with your Belkin's IP, if they're on the different subnet, then the second router must exist.

Comment: If you're suspect your ethernet card, how about use another PC/laptop by connecting to a same port?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the network settings or capabilities are different on your PC than your router and the University network better handles the router settings/capabilities than your PC network card settings/capabilities.

For example, perhaps the router negotiates to 100Mbps Full duplex (100/Full), but your PC is trying to negotiate to Gigabit Full duplex (1000/Full).  In that scenario the PC would work fine going through the router because the router is essentially slowing things down for the University network. Whereas if you connect your PC directly to the University network it is always tripping over lost packets because it's trying to use the faster speed.

I would try manually setting the duplex on your network card to 100/Full or some of the other settings and see if it helps.